# How to add a space between paragraphs when using css reset?

Tags: css, html

What is the safest/no height change cross-browser way to add a space between paragraphs when using css reset?

```
<div>
<p class="text">paragraph1</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p class="text">paragraph2</p>
</div>
<div>
<p class="text">paragraph1</p>
<br>
<br>
<p class="text">paragraph2</p>
</div>
```

[http://jsfiddle.net/unknown601/0ewvk3c9/](http://jsfiddle.net/unknown601/0ewvk3c9/1/)

Comment: Are you talking about whether to use `margin` or `padding`? By the way, every way you're showing is *not* the way you should add spacing, this is what CSS is *for*.

Comment: do you want to move your accept tick to the other answer?

Comment: @Ooker How the tables have turned :D

Comment: after those years... What brings you come back?

Comment: @Ooker I check in, from time to time

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I find it useful to include space between adjacent paragraphs.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kppb0nLx/3/

```
/* a paragraph proceeded by another paragraph will have a top margin */
p + p {
    margin-top: 8px;
}
```

This allows you to keep paragraphs flush with the top/bottom of your container while still having space between them.

The options you listed (`br` and `p` purely for spacing) are not considered good practice. They don't represent the your content semantically and they create extra markup that can easily be replaced with CSS.

[More Reading](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element)

Comment: so how does p + p work?

Comment: Don't know how I've gone all these years and not known about margin collapsing. `:s` @Timothy - [Adjacent selector W3 specification.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors)

Comment: +1 : didn't know about p + p! And this way it doesn't create margin between last p and its container unlike the approved solution :)

Answer (score 5):

The `<br>` tag should only be used to break line i.e `<p>This is first line <br> This is second line.</p>`

For spacing i would have to say on based on my personal experience & on observation of most of the frameworks  `margin` is the best practice to create spacing between paragraph.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0ewvk3c9/7/)**

**CSS:**

```
p{
    margin: 0 0 10px;
}
```

**Edit:** I like @Tim Medora solution much better: `p + p { margin-top: 8px; }` by adding top margin to adjacent p tags  we eliminate the first and last p tag margin issues commonly faced.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - You won't get doubled margins because of margin collapsing: http://jsfiddle.net/kppb0nLx/1/. However, I usually prefer spacing between adjacent paragraphs, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/kppb0nLx/2/

Comment: It also collapses with `display:block` (http://jsfiddle.net/kppb0nLx/4/). But (to your point), `inline-block` is a strange and possibly incorrect choice for a paragraph.

Comment: i think 
 
p{
    margin: 0 0 10px;
}

works the best for me because i have my headings and subheadings <span>

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/unknown601/kppb0nLx/5/

Comment: @Timothy - You should be using the appropriate level `H#` tags (`h1, h2, h3, h4, h5`) for headings, not `span` tags. Please read more about semantic markup at the *More Reading* link in Tim Medora's answer.

Comment: will using h1 fix the heading problem?

Comment: i might have to restyle the whole site with h tags