# How do I get linebreaks to show the blank line between paragraphs in Django?

Tags: html, django

I'm trying to get text from a blog to show on my html page similar to how it shows in the Django admin. I've used both linebreaks and linebreaksbr and the following happens.

What the Django admin shows (and how i'd like it to show as paragraphs):

> This is a test - sentence 1.
>
> This is the second sentence after a line break.

This is the code I have that renders it out on the page:

```
<div class="blog-container">
    <div class="blogs-rendered">
        {% for post in posts %}
        {% if post.published %}
        <div class="posts">
            <p class="title">{{ post.title }}</p>
            <p class="tagline">Created by: {{ post.author }} on {{ post.published_on }}</p>
            {% if post.has_been_updated %}
            <p class="tagline">Updated by: {{ post.author }} on {{ post.updated_on }}</p>
            {% endif %}
            <p class="text">{{ post.body|linebreaksbr }}</p>
            <hr />
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

This is how it shows on the page:[Second sentence on new line without line in between](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mh9Mn.png)

On a side note, if I use linebreaks instead of linebreaksbr it will cancel out all of my CSS code. The CSS code only works with linebreaksbr.

Comment: You could just use css such as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25234345/2785080

Comment: Thanks Ben. I'm wondering though how I separate out each paragraph as it's own section though when going through the for loop to render out {{ post.body }}. Wouldn't I need to have each paragraph it's own field the blog? I'm still new to this so just wondering if there's a way I'm supposed to do that with CSS like you're showing in that thread.

Comment: `post.body` is going to give you the text with paragraph tags between lines: `<p>`. If you want to return them within individual sections, you probably will need a template tag. Look at `initial_letter_filter` to start; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had someone I know help me and we figured out it wasn't working because I had post.body in a p tag instead of a div. It was causing the body to render outside of the container.